# Infinity Sum Ramanujan Identities

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I see in *An Unpublished Manuscript of Ramanujan on identities* of B.C. Berndt a series similar to the following  and I try to sum using [Abel-Plana sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) but I do not sure it is right could you show it. First, define $a_k=(4k+1)\pi$.

**I.** Let $u_1=1+\sqrt{2}$

$$A=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{64 \left(u_1 \sinh \left(a_k\sin \frac{\pi}{8}\right)-\sin \left(a_k\cos \frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right)}{\pi ^5 (4 k+1)^{11} \left(\cos \left(a_k\cos \frac{\pi}{8}\right)+\cosh \left(a_k\sin \frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right)}$$

then

> $$A=\frac{17 \pi ^6 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)}}{60480}+\frac{169 \pi ^6 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}}{302400}$$

**II.** Let $v_1 = 2+\sqrt{2}$ and $v_2 =-2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$

$$B=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{32 \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{v_1}  \sinh \left(a_k\sin \frac{\pi}{16}\right)-v_2 \sin \left(a_k\cos \frac{\pi}{16}\right)\right)}{\pi ^5 (4 k+1)^{11} \left(\cos \left(a_k\cos \frac{\pi}{16}\right)+\cosh \left(a_k\sin \frac{\pi}{16}\right)\right)}$$

then

> $${B=}\frac{ \pi^6}{8}  \left(-\frac{11  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(2-\sqrt{v_1}\right)}}{22680}+\frac{ \left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{v_1}}+\sqrt{v_1 \left(2-\sqrt{v_1}\right)}\right)}{450 \sqrt{2}}+\\ \frac{31  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{v_1}\right)}}{11340}-\frac{17 \left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{v_1}}\right)-\sqrt{v_1 \left(2+\sqrt{v_1}\right)}}{7560 \sqrt{2}}\right)$$